# "Spatial Match" analogue in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, google-earth, reverse-geocoding, layer-file

My question is about reverse geocoding addresses over a large area from a set of points or polygons in ArcMap.

I know from previous experience that Alteryx with the Spatial Match tool allows one to import Google Earth KML files, after which Spatial Match will return addresses. The KML can contain either a polygon (which returns addresses within the polygon), or a set of points (which return addresses at those points).

In ArcMap, I can use the Address Inspector tool to see the data I want, but can't find a way to batch the data out over an area. Setting the search distance doesn't seem to help either. I currently have ESRI World Geocoder and MGRS address locators. Also, it seems I can only import the Google Earth KMLs as a layer file.

Ultimately, how do I do reverse geocode from Google Earth KML on a large scale?